# Custom weighted loss function in Keras for weighing each element

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to create a simple weighted loss function.

Say, I have input dimensions 100 * 5, and output dimensions also 100 * 5. I also have a weight matrix of the same dimension.

Something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
train_X = np.random.randn(100, 5)
train_Y = np.random.randn(100, 5)*0.01 + train_X

weights = np.random.randn(*train_X.shape)
```

#### Defining the custom loss function

```
def custom_loss_1(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred)*weights)
```

#### Defining the model

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras import Model
import keras.backend as K

input_layer = Input(shape=(5,))
out = Dense(5)(input_layer)
model = Model(input_layer, out)
```

#### Testing with existing metrics works fine

```
model.compile('adam','mean_absolute_error')
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=1)
```

#### Testing with our custom loss function doesn't work

```
model.compile('adam',custom_loss_1)
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=10)
```

It gives the following stack trace:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [32,5] vs. [100,5]
 [[Node: loss_9/dense_8_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss_9/dense_8_loss/Abs, loss_9/dense_8_loss/mul/y)]]
```

Where is the number 32 coming from?

#### Testing a loss function with weights as Keras tensors

```
def custom_loss_2(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred)*K.ones_like(y_true))
```

This function seems to do the work. So, probably suggests that a Keras tensor as a weight matrix would work. So, I created another version of the loss function.

#### Loss function try 3

```
from functools import partial

def custom_loss_3(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred)*K.variable(weights, dtype=y_true.dtype))

cl3 = partial(custom_loss_3, weights=weights)
```

Fitting data using cl3 gives the same error as above.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [32,5] vs. [100,5]
     [[Node: loss_11/dense_8_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss_11/dense_8_loss/Abs, loss_11/dense_8_loss/Variable/read)]]
```

I wonder what I'm missing! I could have used the notion of sample_weight in Keras; but then I'd have to reshape my inputs to a 3d vector.

I thought that this custom loss function should really have been trivial.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `model.fit` the batch size is 32 by default, that's where this number is coming from. Here's what's happening:

- In `custom_loss_1` the tensor `K.abs(y_true-y_pred)` has shape `(batch_size=32, 5)`, while the numpy array `weights` has shape `(100, 5)`. This is an invalid multiplication, since the dimensions don't agree and broadcasting can't be applied.
- In `custom_loss_2` this problem doesn't exist because you're multiplying 2 tensors with the same shape `(batch_size=32, 5)`.
- In `custom_loss_3` the problem is the same as in `custom_loss_1`, because converting `weights` into a Keras variable doesn't change their shape.

---

**UPDATE:** It seems you want to give a different weight to each element in each training sample, so the `weights` array should have shape `(100, 5)` indeed.
In this case, I would input your weights' array into your model and then use this tensor within the loss function:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras import Model
import keras.backend as K
from functools import partial


def custom_loss_4(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_true - y_pred) * weights)


train_X = np.random.randn(100, 5)
train_Y = np.random.randn(100, 5) * 0.01 + train_X
weights = np.random.randn(*train_X.shape)

input_layer = Input(shape=(5,))
weights_tensor = Input(shape=(5,))
out = Dense(5)(input_layer)
cl4 = partial(custom_loss_4, weights=weights_tensor)
model = Model([input_layer, weights_tensor], out)
model.compile('adam', cl4)
model.fit(x=[train_X, weights], y=train_Y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, `model.compile('adam',custom_loss_1)
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=10, batch_size=len(train_Y))` works. Would it be possible to correctly use the corresponding batch from the weight matrix?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the purpose of this weighted loss. Do you want to have a different weight for each training example, or rather a different weight for each "class"?

Comment: I'm trying to use a different weight for each "class". However, my outputs are real-valued variables. A lot of them are zeros. A. very few of them are say, greater than 10. So, it's a case of imbalance, which I'm trying to cover using weighing. Something like - give lower weight to 0s and higher weight to anything more than zero. Without weighting, I end up predicting zeros!

Comment: In that case, you should only have a different weight for each class (i.e. only 5 weights, not 100*5 weights). Your code will work if you define weights as: `weights = np.random.randn(5)`

Comment: Actually, the notion of 100*5 weights comes from the fact that different samples (the 100 dimension) can have different amount of zero and non-zero values. Think of it in this way that given a 100*5 matrix with a lot of zeros, I want to give higher weight to non-zeros, which can occur anywhere in the matrix.

Comment: Ok. Please correct me if I'm wrong: if `train_Y[i, :]` is an array with 5 zeros, then you want to give sample `i` a low weight, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162447/discussion-between-nipun-batra-and-rvinas).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127646/1447257 custom losses taking multiple inputs can be added with `Model.add_loss`

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I got this error: https://i.postimg.cc/6qwP5Bsr/error.png . I also asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74425890/how-to-define-specific-coefficients-for-each-input-feature-to-increase-and-decre. I need to find the solution. I don't understand why a person commented and denied it.

Comment: This error: TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_3'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by ...

Comment: ...You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.