# How to implement pixelwise weighting of loss function in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras 2.2.4 and I am trying to implement a loss function for pixel-wise classification as described in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.10486.pdf) but I am having some of the difficulties presented here. I am doing 3D segmentation, therefore my target vector is `(b_size, width_x, width_y, width_z, nb_classes)`. I implemented the following loss function where weight map is the same shape as target and prediction vector:

```
def dice_xent_loss(y_true, y_pred, weight_map):

    """Adaptation of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.10486.pdf for multilabel 
    classification with overlapping pixels between classes. Dec 2018.
    """
    loss_dice = weighted_dice(y_true, y_pred, weight_map)
    loss_xent = weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weight_map)

    return loss_dice + loss_xent

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weight_map):
    return tf.reduce_mean((K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, 
                                                 y_pred)*weight_map)) / (tf.reduce_sum(weight_map) + K.epsilon())

def weighted_dice(y_true, y_pred, weight_map):

    if weight_map is None:
        raise ValueError("Weight map cannot be None")
    if y_true.shape != weight_map.shape:
        raise ValueError("Weight map must be the same size as target vector")

    dice_numerator = 2.0 * K.sum(y_pred * y_true * weight_map, axis=[1,2,3])
    dice_denominator = K.sum(weight_map * y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + \
                                                             K.sum(y_pred * weight_map, axis=[1,2,3])
    loss_dice = (dice_numerator) / (dice_denominator + K.epsilon())
    h1=tf.square(tf.minimum(0.1,loss_dice)*10-1)
    h2=tf.square(tf.minimum(0.01,loss_dice)*100-1)
    return 1.0 - tf.reduce_mean(loss_dice) + \
            tf.reduce_mean(h1)*10 + \
            tf.reduce_mean(h2)*10
```

I am compiling the model using `sample_weights=temporal` as suggested and I am passing the weights to the `model.fit` as `sample_weight=weights`. Still I get the following error:

```
File "overfit_one_case.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
File "overfit_one_case.py", line 81, in main
   sample_weight_mode="temporal")
 File "/home/igt/anaconda2/envs/niftynet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 342, in compile
sample_weight, mask)
File "/home/igt/anaconda2/envs/niftynet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 404, in weighted
score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
TypeError: dice_xent_loss() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

In  `training_utils.py` Keras is calling my custom loss without any weights. Any idea on how to solve this? Another constraint that I have is that I am trying to do transfer learning on this particular model. Therefore, I cannot add `weight_map` to the `Input` layer as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082655/custom-weighted-loss-function-in-keras-for-weighing-each-element).

Answer (score 2):

Sample weights are weights for samples, not for pixels.

Keras losses never take any other argument besides `y_true` and `y_pred`. All keras weighting is automatic.

For custom weights, you need to implement them yourself. You can create these loss functions wrapped inside a function that takes weights, like this:

```
def weighted_dice_xent_loss(weight_map):

    def dice_xent_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        #code...    
        return loss_dice + loss_xent
    return dice_xent_loss

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(weight_map):
    def inner_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(
           (K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)*weight_map)) / (
            tf.reduce_sum(weight_map) + K.epsilon())
        return inner_binnary_crossentropy

def weighted_dice(weight_map):
    def dice(y_true, y_pred):

    #code....
        return 1.0 - tf.reduce_mean(loss_dice) + \
            tf.reduce_mean(h1)*10 + \
            tf.reduce_mean(h2)*10
   return dice
```

Use them as `loss=weighted_dice_xent_loss(weight_map)`, for instance.

---

Ugly workaround for using sample weights.

If your weights are unique for every sample, then you must turn every pixel into a sample (something very unusual).

With your data:

- Flatten the first dimensions of your data like `(b_size * width_x * width_y * width_z, nb_channels)`.
- Flatten your weight matrices the same way.
- Flatten your true outputs the same way

With your model:

- Create a compatible `inputs = Input((nb_channels,))
- Reshape in a `Lambda` layer using `K.reshape` to restore original dimensions: `K.reshape(x, (-1, width_x, width_y, width_z, nb_classes))`
- Make the rest of the model as usual
- Reshape the output in a `Lambda` layer using `K.reshape(x, (-1, nb_classes))`

With your losses:

- Calculate the losses per pixel, do not sum pixels.
- Keras weights will be summed after you calculated the loss (thus it will be incompatible with dice)